# How can I trigger an action after displaying results in Select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I'd like to trigger an action after select2 display the results.
The 'select2:open' event triggers the action AFTER the select2 is opened but BEFORE it displays the results.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Select2` will trigger a few different events when different actions are taken using the component, allowing you to add custom hooks and perform actions.

As far as I understand you need something like `select2:loaded` action. Unfortunately there **is no such event** right now, according the [documentation](https://select2.github.io/options.html#events).

Try to use `select2:select` - This is triggered before the drop-down is opened, this event can be prevented or `select2:closing`.